# Can't start any kde program - hang at connect(AF_FILE, "/tmp/fam-username-")

Tags: freeze, kde

In my kde 3.5 session I can't start any kde application (kate, kmail, kwrite, ...). I click on it but it will not start.

If I'll run `strace kwrite` from console; the very last line will be

```
 connect(11, {sa_family=AF_FILE, path=@/tmp/fam-username-}, 110^C <unfinished ...>
```

This system call will not finish if I will not press a Ctrl-C. Some applications are freezed for 3 days already.

I want to save my current session. How can I fix the problem without relogin and reboot?

I'm using Gamin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try searching for and killing an old gam_server process.

See [here](http://web.archiveorange.com/archive/v/91Me9XgmwsG4cyXvmxRw) for more info.

Comment: is it part of gamin?

Comment: The link is dead. Is more info available elsewhere?

Answer (score 0):

what are the permissions of /tmp?

In debian I had had it several times that installing a package altered /tmp permission. Maybe the happend to you?

Also the trace mentions "fam" (file alteration monitor) does it run? What does happen if you stop/start (/etc/init.d/fam ?)

Comment: rwxrwxrwt. I hav no root access and no /etc/init.d/fam file